# Laravel Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: laravel, localhost

When running a Laravel app on  a server online I get the following error after trying to hit an API:

```
Class name must be a valid object or a string
"line": 765,
"file": "/var/www/html/live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
"class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
```

But when i run the same app locally everything works fine, i can use this API and this error disappear.

Anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: What version of PHP is the server running? What version are you running locally? What version of Laravel?
You may want to try running php artisan config:cache on the server as well.